# Do i need Java for running hadoop in Amazon EC2?

Tags: java, php, hadoop, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Do i need to learn Java for running hadoop in Amazon EC2?

I am a PHP/C++ developer and no experience in Java.

Just planning to setup hadoop cluster in Amazon cloud. Is hive/pig is sufficient or i need java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given Hadoop itself is written in Java it helps to know Java but if you are simply setting it up and you can get by by using HIVE or PIG, you don't really need to know Java programming.

If this is only to get familiar with Hadoop that strategy may work but if you want to run into production then you will need some amount of familiarity with how JVM works and such. You may not need to code in Java though.

Comment: Thanks, should i start with general java programming/basics or something else (as you mentioned JVM)?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. If you are trying to program (for ex: MapReduce jobs) then start with Java programming. If you are simply trying to install and run Hadoop start with learning about JVM and how it works.

Comment: yes my requirement is write map/reduce functions... thanks for feedback. Better to start with java basics :)